# Assigning default value to table using form MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am attempting to create a form that can import data from another database into access, assign an import ID to all the records, copy that data into a master database, and then delete the imported databases so the only remaining databases are the master databases.

I am getting stuck on assigning the import ID. I would like the user to be able to define it in a form and hit a button that executes assigning the value in the form to all the new sets of data. Since this column is not defined in the original set of data I figured the easiest way to do this would be by setting the default value on the master database before copying the data over. However I cannot find a way to change this value without clicking over to the form and changing it manually, which is the exact opposite of what I need to happen.

The reason that I am trying to add the import ID is that I need to nest child tables in the main table and the existing ID starts at 1 for every database and does not remain unique. I figure that I can use the import ID and the existing ID to create a relationship.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what are you porting to (another access DB or an mysql/mssql?)
but you should be able to set a field in **both** databases being a integer and using a form to set that field data to whatever the user enters (remember to parse). After the data is set on our outgoing DB you can just push to your master like normal (unless i have not understood the question?) to drop a database in SQL use

```
DROP DATABASE database_name
```

You could also use java or .net to delete the database manually after you run you update